# Is it possible to make .dll/.so library from Python code?

Tags: python, sqlite

I am working with SQLite and I use some extensions such as:

```
def foo(value):
    return ['foo','bar'][bool(value)]
```

It is easy to load this function from the `sqlite3` module, but when using the database from not Python e.g. `DB Browser for SQLite`, I need to access my `foo` function, so I need to load a library extension.

Is there a way to make a dynamic library from my `foo` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can, as long as you have a C-Compiler available.

I used pyrex to embedd python into a Linux PAM-Module and
i used C-Types to embbed Python into a Windows DLL. With hindsight, the 
pyrex solution was much fatser to develop and less complicated.

Pyrex provides an example.

Ctypes: http://starship.python.net/crew/theller/ctypes/
Pyrex: http://www.cosc.canterbury.ac.nz/~greg/python/Pyrex/

Comment: `Pyrex` is an old fork of `Cython` and it doesn't look that it is made to write C extensions, but Python extensions written in C. Am I wrong?